# Regex for matching all words between a set of curly braces

Tags: ruby, regex

A simple question for most regex experts I know, but I'm trying to return all matches for the words between some curly braces in a sentence; however Ruby is only returning a single match, and I cannot figure out why exactly.

I'm using this example sentence:

```
sentence = hello {name} is {thing}
```

with this regex to try and return both "{name}" and "{thing}":

```
sentence[/\{(.*?)\}/]
```

However, Ruby is only returning "{name}".  Can anyone explain why it doesn't match for both words?

Comment: Because you're only telling it to match once. (If I actually knew Ruby, I'd turn that into an answer.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're close, but using the wrong method:

```
sentence = "hello {name} is {thing}"

sentence.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/)
# => [["name"], ["thing"]]
```

Comment: Ahh, I was looking under the Regex class, I didn't even see that scan method under String.  Thanks.  I modified it a bit to just

sentence.scan(/\{.*?\}/)

as I realized with scan, I didn't have to do the groups, and to include the curly braces in the match.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One can do that using a *positive lookbehind*, `(?<=\{)`, to require that the match be immediately preceded by a left brace, and a *positive lookahead*, to require that the match be immediately followed by a right brace.

```
str = "hello {name} is {thing}"
str.scan /(?<={).*?(?=})/
  #=> ["name", "thing"]
```

If there could be nested braces and only the strings within the inner braces were desired, `.*?` needs to be replace with `[^{]*?`:

```
str = "hello {my {name} is {thing} from} the swamp"
str.scan /(?<={)[^{]*?(?=})/
  #=> ["name", "thing"]
```

Comment: To match double brackets `/(?<=\{\{).*?(?=\}\})/`